# MongoDB best schema for filterable, dynamic attributes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-design, nosql, schema

I have a large collection of users. Each user can have roles. I want to be able to filter users based on which role they have. Is there a performance difference between the following two approaches? I can imagine the second approach is faster and more appropriate for my use case. I also hypothesize the index for the second one would be smaller. Any ideas? Thanks!

Array approach

```json
{
  name: "Paul",
  roles: [
    "system administrator",
    "network administrator",
    "solutions architect"
  ]
}
```

Attribute approach

```json
{
  name: "Paul",
  roles: {
    system_administrator: true,
    network_administrator: true
    solutions_architect: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is better, because you can easily add/remove/update items in your `roles` array using array operators like `$push`, `$pull` etc.

Also, indexing the first type is easier, as you'd just index `roles` field.

For the next option, if you want to specifically index each type of role, you will have to create a lot of indexes.

So my vote will be for first!